# Question regarding Hall's wedding theorem proof.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $(G,U,V)$ be a bipartite graph.

In the proof of the theorem, we show that if for each $U'\subseteq U$ we have $\left |N(U')  \right |\geq \left |U'  \right |$, we can find a perfect matching for $U$.

My question is why do we have to work "hard" while we can just take $\;U' = U$ and by elementary set theory get a bijection between $U\;$ and $N(U)$ because we have $\left |N(U)  \right |\geq \left |U \right |$?

Answer (score 3):

Note first that if $|N(U)| > U$, then we can only find an *injective* mapping from $U$ to $V$ (i.e. every element in $U$ gets matched to a unique element in $V$, but not every element of $V$ is mapped to by an element in $U$).

That aside, when using Hall's theorem we are interested in a bijection that only includes a mapping from $u \in U$ to $u' \in U'$ *only if there is an edge from $u$ to $u'$ in $G$*. If you could use any edge from a vertex in $U$ to a vertex in $V$ (even if it didn't exist in $G$) then the problem would be come trivial.

As an example, consider the empty complete graph $\overline{K_{3,3}}$. If we take $U' = U$, we still can't find a bijection using *only* edges that exist in the graph - because there are none!

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking why the condition for a perfect matching for $U$ is $\lvert N(U') \rvert \geq \lvert U' \rvert$ for every subset $U' \subseteq U$ instead of $\lvert N(U) \rvert \geq \lvert U \rvert$.

Consider the following example. Let $(G, U, V)$ be the bipartite graph given by $G = \{ G_1, G_2, G_3\}$, $U = \{ U_1, U_2, U_3 \}$, and $V = \{ (U_1, G_1), (U_1, G_2), (U_1, G_3), (U_2, G_3), (U_3, G_3) \}$. This graph has no perfect matching for $U$, since edges in a matching must be pairwise non-adjacent. However, $\lvert N(U) \rvert = 3 \geq 3 = \lvert U \rvert$.

Another way to understand this is to see that a perfect matching on $U$ is necessarily a perfect matching on all subsets $U' \subseteq U$ in the bipartite subgraph $(N(U'), U', V')$, where $V' = \{ v = (u,g) \in V : u \in U', g \in G \} \subseteq V$. If there is any subset of $U' \subseteq U \setminus U^*$ such that $\lvert N(U') \rvert < \lvert U' \rvert$, then there can be no perfect matching on $U'$, which means there can be no perfect matching on $U$.